# Triggering an on exit event after clicking a button

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to trigger an on exit event after clicking an OK button in order to format a particular event before the number is stored. This works when you click a different input, then click okay, but I am trying to get the OK button to trigger this formatting in the case where this is the last input they update. This is a multitab form, so setting focus on a random input doesn't work. My Multipage.setfocus does not trigger the on exit event.

```
Private Sub InputPropertyCapRate_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    InputPropertyCapRate.Text = Format(InputPropertyCapRate / 100, "#,0.0#%")
End Sub


Private Sub ButtonOK_Click()
    MultiPage.SetFocus
    Unload DealInfo
End Sub
```

Comment: Create a separate method which will be called from both event handlers, `Exit()` and `Click()`.

Comment: Another option is to call the event itself.  It's just a Sub.

Comment: Thank you @KostasK. and Brian M Stafford, my only issue is when I try to call all of the exit subs one after another, there is an error because all of the inputs are on different tabs, and you can't access these inputs when said tab is not active.

Comment: Activate them then to get access to those inputs, and deactivate them in your code